# Alert on changing the page in ViewPager2

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager2

I want an alert dialog to be shown, when an user scrolls from one page to the other inside a ViewPager2. I know about `OnPageChangeCallback` interface, but cannot figure out how to use it.

```
class showAlert() : Fragment(){
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        ...

        binding?.ViewPager?.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback(){
            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
                createAlert()
            }
        })
    }
        ...

private fun createAlert() : Dialog {
         return AlertDialog.Builder(childFragmentManager)
             .setTitle("Exit?")
             .setMessage("If you leave, then the data will be lost")
             .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.VideoView_error_text_unknown, new onClickListener())
    }

        ...
 
}
```

Again, the whole point is, when the user scrolls from one fragment to another inside the viewpager, an alert dialog should be shown, asking it whether it wants to move to another fragment or not.

Comment: do you also create and show the dialog? there seems to be a `create()` missing at the end of `createAlert()`. And you also don't call `show()`. Like for example `createAlert().show()`

Comment: The code is actually incomplete. I am quite confused like how to go around this.